# Sort dynamic dropdown list alphabetically

Tags: c#, sorting, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a dropdown with three strings horizontally for each item. How can I alphabetically sort first by string 1 from each item, then by string 2 from each item?

Here's my snippet:

```
foreach (var item in list)
{
    if(typeof(T).Equals(typeof(Machine)))
    {
        Machine machine = (item as Machine);
        string title = machine.MachineName + " - " + machine.Serial + " - " + machine.MachineOwnership;
        alert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create(title, UIAlertActionStyle.Default, action => {
            button.SetTitle(title, UIControlState.Normal);
        }));
    }
    else if(typeof(T).Equals(typeof(Person)))
    {
        alert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create((item as Person).Name, UIAlertActionStyle.Default, action => {
            button.SetTitle((item as Person).Name, UIControlState.Normal);
        }));
    }
}
```

Where `list` contains objects of type `Machine` which has the following properties:

`MachineName`, `Serial` and `MachineOwnshership` (all strings).

So I want to do something like `OrderBy(MachineName).ThenBy(Serial)` but not sure how to do so correctly when I'm first checking to see what the list type is and then populating the dropdown list per item.

My dropdown list looks something like this if anyone needs clarification:

```
-------------------------------------------------
MachineNameStartsWithA - 01234 - OwnerStartsWithA
--------------------------------------------------
MachineNameStartsWithB - 012345 - OwnerStartsWithB
---------------------------------------------------
```

etc.... where it's a long list of items where the strings are separated by "-" like it's shown in the code.

Also, for what it's worth, this is currently inside a Xamarin app.

Comment: You could load the data to a data table first, do sorts and filters on the data table and then use that table as the combo datasource.  I had done something like this in the past with a multi-column combo box, but I am guessing you dont have that option.

Comment: I don't think I have that option. This code is written inside a Xamarin app. I don't think I have option to use DataTables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think something like this should work. Sorting by a `Tuple` should be lexicographic:

```
list.OfType<Machine>().OrderBy(x => new Tuple<string,string>(x.MachineName,x.Serial))
```

The `OfType` call should also remove the need for the `typeof` check and cast - the result should be an iterable of `Machine`s.

---

Per the comment regarding multiple object types:

**Grouping like types together**

This would be my default preference from a UI/UX perspective unless it really makes sense to mix `Machine`s and `Person`s together. Depending on the length of the `list` it may be preferable to split on the element type first as `list.OfType` will enumerate the entire list each time.

```
foreach(var item in list.OfType<Machine>().OrderBy(x => new Tuple<string,string>(x.MachineName,x.Serial)))
{
  // append item
}
foreach(var item in list.OfType<Person>().OrderBy(x => x.Name))
{
  // append item
}
```

**Interleaving various types**

```
private Tuple<string,string> Projection(BaseClass x)
{
    Machine item = x as Machine;
    if(item != null)
    {
      return new Tuple<string,string>(item.MachineName,item.Serial);
    }

    Person item = x as Person;
    if(item != null)
    {
      return new Tuple<string,string>(item.Name,"");
    }
}

foreach(var item in list.OrderBy(Projection))
{
  // check type of item and append as appropriate
}
```

Comment: I get "Non-invocable member 'Tuple' cannot be used like a method." when I use Tuple...

Comment: @Euridice01 Yeah sorry it's been a while since I've written C#. It should be corrected now.

Comment: Ok thanks. Now, my stupid question is where should this snippet go in my code. before I iterate through the list or after. I have to add a check to see if the list is of type machine before trying to order it.

Comment: @Euridice01 It should replace `list` in your `foreach` and remove the need for the subsequent type check and cast. The result will be an iterable of `Machine`s ordered first by `MachineName`, then `Serial`. It does not sort the list in place, though it would be possible to do so similarly using `Sort`.

Comment: The problem I'm having now that I didn't show is I'm doing several type checks inside the foreach() for list...where the same list could be a type of Person, Collection, etc...

Comment: @Euridice01 How would you like to see those interleave when sorted? Or should all the `Person`s be sequential, then all the `Machine`s, etc.? I'll update my answer with a couple possibilities.

Comment: ideally but like Person doesn't have several properties to sort by like Machine does. So not sure how you would best handle that scenario. If there's a good way to do it dynamically, by all means, show me. Otherwise, you can assume the simplest way right now and just focus on Machine being sortable and the other checks just there inside the foreach loop. I also edited my post to show another else if if you're curious.

Comment: @Euridice01 Unfortunately I'm unable to access chat. If you are looking to interleave them all, you would have to map them all to the same interface (a `Tuple` of however many elements you maximally need). Any objects that have fewer fields would use the empty string for the remainder. Personally, I would probably, depending on your precise application, use option groups to title and keep like objects together.

Comment: @Euridice01 I updated the answer with the two options I see. Personally, I would prefer the former unless there is a good reason not to.

Comment: @Euridice01 Sure thing. Let me know if anything doesn't work or doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Euridice01 Can you post your updated code, the output you're seeing, and the output you are looking to achieve?

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake LOL. I just realized, I forgot to remove the machine check inside the other foreach, so it overwrote my first loop xD. It works, thank you!